# Переход между мобильной и полной версией

Tags: php, javascript, мобильная-разработка, jquery-mobile

Есть мобильная и полная версия сайта. Как грамотно организовать переход между версиями?
В мобильных браузерах в меню так же есть пункты меню для выбора полной либо мобильной версией. Как сделать чтобы они были применимы к моему сайту?

Comment: можно измерить ширину экрана устройства, если они меньше 700px то рекредитить на мобильную версию, так же можно использовать это же устройство на по ОС использованному на устройстве.

Comment: Сейчас я делаю редирект, по типу ОС устройства.

Comment: можно комбинировать оба условия что бы исключить устройства вроде больших айпадов и подобных

Comment: А как тогда сделать пункт меню мобильного браузера "полная/мобильная версия сайта"? Может для этого мета тег какой-нить используется, либо js функция есть какая-нить?

Comment: Как раз для айпадов и нужно привязать меню браузера, к версиям сайта

Comment: Мне кажется, что так будет правильней

Comment: в таком случае при редиректе из полной версии можно давать кук клиенту, после чего он будет редиректиться на мобильную. на мобильной можно поместить ссылку на полную. при возвращении до проверки на ширину экрана и ОС, можно проверить на наличие кука и его возраст, если он молод то не делать ридерект, если стар или отсутствует редиректить на мобильную версию

Comment: Это понятно. Но сейчас меня больше интересует вопрос взаимодействия с самим мобильным брауезером. Точнее с его пунктом меню переключения "полной/мобильной" версии. Как заставить браузер понять , какой адрес мобильной, а кокой полной версии?

Comment: Если я правильно понял то у вас два разных адреса как example.com и mobile.example.com можно оставить эту js функцию только на десктопной версии сайта или написать ее противопроложность для мобильной

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли, два адреса.

Comment: Но я не то имел в виду. Есть мобильный браузер, у мобильного браузера есть пункт "полная/мобильна". И этому пункту нужно дать понять, какой адрес - мобильный, какой полный.

Answer (score 3):

Жава скриптом:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://m.server.com";
  }
```

//опредееление по  заголовку

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){

if(document.URL !="http://m.server.com/")
  {
    window.location ="http://m.server.com/";
  }
}
  //-->
</script>
```

.htaccess оприделяет поддерживает ли браузер мобильные типы()

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://m.server.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

php версия:

```
$isMobile = (bool)preg_match('#\b(ip(hone|od|ad)|android|opera m(ob|in)i|windows (phone|ce)|blackberry|tablet'.

                    '|s(ymbian|eries60|amsung)|p(laybook|alm|rofile/midp|laystation portable)|nokia|fennec|htc[\-_]'.

                    '|mobile|up\.browser|[1-4][0-9]{2}x[1-4][0-9]{2})\b#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );



if($isMobile) {

    header('Location: m.server.com');

}
```

[аналог в английской ветке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649767/best-way-to-detect-mobile-device-and-redirect)

Comment: можно еще привязать кукис,если вдруг пользователь упорно хочет мобильную версию вместо обычной, тогда перенаправлять на нужную версию сайта или  автоматом редиректить если у пользователя нет определенной "куки" ,всетакже есть уже ответ на ваш вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess/4208300#4208300